# Counting all sub-sets that are not forming forbidden combinations

Tags: algorithm, graph, combinatorics

I'm trying to solve pretty complex problem with combinatorics and graphs:

Given is a undirected graph with *n* (*n*<=30) nodes and *m* (*m*<=50) edges, each edge is represented in the format *a*, *b*, where *a, b* are both nodes in the graph.

Now in this graph we have to count all subsets of nodes, clearly there are 2^*n* subsets, however we have one restriction in each sub-set combination we shouldn't have triplet of nodes that are forming triangle, and we should not count those combinations, in other words we shouldn't count combinations which include nodes that have cycle of length 3.

**Example**

*n=3, m=3* and we have the graph *2-1*, *3-1*, *2-3*, the answer for this example is 7 and all the sub-sets we can form are: {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, however we should not count the subset {1,2,3} because the nodes 1,2,3 are forming triangle, in other words they are forming cycle of length 3

**What I have tried**

I solved the problem with correct answer, but it only works when *n*<=22, actually I'm generating all possible bitmasks with O(2^*n*) complexity, but this complexity is too big for *n=30*. What should I add to my algorithm to make it work for all test cases?

Comment: You know how many subsets there are. If you find a triangle, how many subsets contain that triangle? If you find two triangles, how many subsets contain both triangles?

Comment: Find all triangles, than for each node store triangles it is in (enough to store other triangle nodes for node with largest index), and than with a backtracking find combinations by checking is node in any triangle and are other two triangle nodes already selected.

Comment: @Ante can you explain the backtracking part a little bit more because I don't really understand you since there are 30 nodes I think that backtracking is going to be in 2^30 complexity

Comment: @someone12321 I misunderstood question, I thought problem is to print all subsets, not just number of subsets. I deleted my answer. As m69 described, you need [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) A_i are subsets that contain triangle i. Problem is that summation is on every subset of triangles, that can be much larger than number of all subset of nodes. Each summand is of type |intersection A_x| = 2^(n-number_of_different_nodes_in_trias), which can be used to simplify summation.

Comment: @Ante I think that your formula wont work, because we can count the combinations where 1 or 2 nodes from the other triangle are turned on

Comment: @someone12321 It works :-) The easiest is to check with only one triangle. Than solution is |S| - |A_1| = 2^n - 2^(n-3). That includes subsets with one or two triangle nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving this efficiently is of course to only calculate how many subsets with or without triangles there are, and not to actually generate any subsets to check them.

As you say, a graph with n nodes has 2<sup>n</sup> possible subsets, and each possible n-sized bit pattern represents one of those subsets. Notice that we do not need to generate these subsets to calculate how many there are.

Now, imagine that after checking the edges we find one triangle. How many of the 2<sup>n</sup> subsets contain all three nodes that make up this triangle? All n-sized bit patterns with the three corresponding bits always set to 111 represent all subsets that contain those three nodes. The number of these bit patterns is obviously 2<sup>n-3</sup>. So if we have n nodes and 1 triangle, we have 2<sup>n</sup>-2<sup>n-3</sup> subsets that don't contain the triangle.

If there are 2 or more triangles, the question is: how many additional subsets should we subtract from the total? Suppose there are 2 triangles, and they don't share any of their nodes. Then the one triangle excludes 2<sup>n-3</sup> subsets, and the number of subsets that contain the second triangle but not the first (we don't want to exclude any subsets twice) is 7/8 × 2<sup>n-3</sup>, because they correspond to all n-sized bit patterns with 3 bits always set to 111 and 3 other bits set to either 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, but not 111. So if we have n nodes and 2 seperate triangles, we have 2<sup>n</sup>-2<sup>n-3</sup>-7/8×2<sup>n-3</sup> subsets that don't contain a triangle.

If there is a third triangle that doesn't share any nodes with the first two triangles, we exclude an additional 49/64×2<sup>n-3</sup> subsets, because there are two groups of 3 bits that must not be 111, so that makes 7/8 × 7/8 × 2<sup>n-3</sup>.

So what happens if two triangles share a node? The 3 bits corresponding to the second triangle must be 111, and the 3 bits corresponding to the first triangle must not be 111, so count 00111, 01111, 10111 but not 11111. So that gives 2<sup>n</sup>-2<sup>n-3</sup>-3/4×2<sup>n-3</sup>.

If two triangles share two nodes, we count 0111 but not 1111, so that gives 2<sup>n</sup>-2<sup>n-3</sup>-1/2×2<sup>n-3</sup>.

As you see, by finding how many triangles there are, and how many nodes they share, you can calculate how many subsets without triangles there are, without actually having to generate the subsets and checking them for triangles.

---

EXAMPLE

We have 50 nodes and 30 edges. After checking the edges, we find these triangles:

```
A.        B.        C.  D.        E.        G.  H.

  N         N         N   N         N         N - N
 / \       / \       / \ / \       / \       / \ /
N - N     N - N     N - N - N     N - N     N - N
                                   \ /       \ /
                                    N         N

                                  F.        I.
```

The total number of subsets is 2<sup>50</sup>.
The number of subsets containing triangle A is 2<sup>47</sup>.
The number of subsets containing B but not A is 7/8 × 2<sup>47</sup>.
The number of subsets containing C but not A or B is 7/8 × 7/8 × 2<sup>47</sup>.
The number of subsets containing D but not A to C is 7/8 × 7/8 × 3/4 × 2<sup>47</sup>.
The number of subsets containing E but not A to D is 7/8 × 7/8 × 25/32 × 2<sup>47</sup>.
The number of subsets containing F but not A to E is 7/8 × 7/8 × 25/32 × 1/2 × 2<sup>47</sup>.
The number of subsets containing G but not A to F is 7/8 × 7/8 × 25/32 × 3/16 × 2<sup>47</sup>.
The number of subsets containing H but not A to G is 7/8 × 7/8 × 25/32 × 3/16 × 1/2 × 2<sup>47</sup>.
The number of subsets containing I but not A to H is 7/8 × 7/8 × 25/32 × 3/16 × 1/2 × 1/2 × 2<sup>47</sup>.

2<sup>50</sup> - (1 + 7/8 + 49/64 + 147/256 + 1225/2048 + 1225/4096 + 3675/32768 + 3675/65536 + 3675/131072) × 2<sup>47</sup> = 1,125,899,906,842,624 - 606,343,081,754,624 = 519,556,825,088,000

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think that the implementation in code will be pretty hard since we have to work with fractions, how can this be implemented in easiest way?

Comment: @someone12321 7/8×2^47 is of course 7×2^44, so that won't be a problem. But it's true that turning this answer into code will not be trivial.

Comment: Also can you explain me how do you get the part(25/32) E but not A to D is 7/8 × 7/8 × 25/32 × 247. Why do you get(25/32)?

Comment: @someone12321 Yes, that's the difficult part. For every cluster of triangles, you have to calculate how many of the possibilities lead to one or more triangles. With C and D, who share a node, that's 5 bits with the middle bit shared by the two triangles; 11100, 11101, 11110 and 11111 have C, while 00111, 01111, 10111 and (again) 11111 have D; so that's 32 combinations of which 7 have already been excluded, so (32-7)/32 = 25/32. I don't know what the easiest way is to calculate this for all types of clusters.